# android: activity shows as a black screen when debugger is connected

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

When debugger is connected, one of my activities in an Android app is displayed as a black screen. When I run the application without debugger, everything is working normally. If debugger is connected and then I disconnect it, black screen disappears and ui is displayed normally.
Any ideas why that might be?
I reproduced the problem on two phones. Restarting the phone, uninstalling app, cleaning the project didn't do anything for me.
EDIT: onCreate() in the black screen activity doesn't even get called.. though the startActivity(intent) for it gets called.

Answer (score 2):

Its not like that...Usually when you debug the application it will be very slow when compared to the normal behavior. You might be performing any task in onCreate() method that takes a bit time to execute. Until that is done UI wont be display.

I suggest you to keep some debug breakpoints and analyse where it is taking much time...

Comment: It turns out that onCreate() in the black screen activity doesn't even get called...

Comment: Hey did you kept startActivity() in try catch block. Once check is it going into catch block if it is unable to start activity.???

Answer (score 2):

This also happened to me. Black screen after calling start activity and the `onCreate` of the next activity is not reached.

What I did was remove all the breakpoints on the called activity and all is good.